# Term for the sum of products of a number's prime factors, excluding one factor per product.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology

Is there a term for the sum of products of a number's prime factors, excluding one factor per product?

For example $30 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$

So the sum of products of "all but one prime factors" is $2 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 5 + 3 \cdot 5 = 31$

For $15=3\cdot 5$, it would be $3 + 5 = 8$.

Comment: Do you mean "all but one *prime* factors"?

Comment: @Spencer, yes, editing the post now

Comment: What would that sum be for 100?

Comment: 100 = 2 * 2 * 5 * 5, so it would be 2*2*5 + 2*2*5 + 2*5*5 + 2*5*5 = 140

Comment: So if $N=2^{\nu_2(N)}3^{\nu_3(N)}5^{\nu_5(N)}7^{\nu_7(N)}\cdots$, then the sum you're after is $$N\left({\nu_2(N)\over2}+{\nu_3(N)\over3}+{\nu_5(N)\over5}+{\nu_7(N)\over7}+\cdots\right)$$ right?

Comment: @BarryCipra yes exactly!

Comment: This is related to pseudoperfect numbers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This function is called the [arithmetic derivative](http://oeis.org/A003415) of a number.

Here's a recursive definition:

- Define $0' = 1' = 0$
- Define $p' = 1$ for any prime.
- If a number $m = a\cdot b$, define $m' = a'\cdot b + a \cdot b'$.

By induction you see that this equals your "sum of all but 1 prime factor" function.

Comment: As a general comment: if you have a formula that outputs positive integers for integer inputs, you can try to compute manually the first 7-10 terms and type it into OEIS. More frequently than not you will find what it is and who has previously studied it.

Answer (score 10):

This is the *arithmetic derivative*, [OEIS A003415](https://oeis.org/A003415).

The arithmetic derivative $n'$ satisfies $(mn)'=m'n+mn'$ for all $m,n$, just like the ordinary derivative. From this we get $(abc)'=a'bc+ab'c+abc'$ and so on, and clearly these also apply in the cases where all the variables are prime numbers and $p'=1$.

Comment: It makes sense to define $f(p)=1$ because $f(p)$ is the sum of one empty product and we usually define the empty product as $1$.  This is one example of where it is convenient to do so.

Comment: @RossMillikan: there's an interesting parallel between arithmetic derivatives and tensor derivations. For tensor derivations one requires that Leibniz rule holds, and then the specification of the action on scalars (as action by a vector field) and on vectors uniquely determines the derivation. Here, the action on $1$ is restricted (like the action on scalars). The action on $p$ can be arbitrary, and for each choice of action on $p$ one develops a version of the arithmetic derivative. This is to emphasize the **convenience** you mentioned in your comment, and how it relates to the OP.